# Will 'git push origin <branch>' remove <branch> remotely after removing it locally?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm following the [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) model and I have a doubt.

First, I add a new feature branch from 'develop':

```
# Checkout from develop branch
$ git checkout -b <branch>
# Push and track <branch>
$ git push --set-upstream origin <branch>
```

After the feature is finished, I follow *Incorporating a finished feature on develop*:

```
# Switch to 'develop'
$ git checkout develop
# Merge <branch> into 'develop'
$ git merge --no-ff <branch>
# Remove <branch> locally
$ git branch -d <branch>
# Remove <branch> remotely <-- ???
$ git push origin develop
```

The last command is the one that I'm not sure about. Will it remove remotely the `<branch>` I just removed locally?

Comment: I'm assuming <branch> was pulled initially from origin. No, that branch will remain

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: So you're running `get push origin develop` after you've deleted the `develop` branch from your local repo. (I don't know the answer, I'm just clarifying what you're asking since there may have been some confusion.)

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob I added info on how `<branch>` is created.

Comment: @hobbs I didn't. I used the `git push origin --delete <branch>` command but then I saw the instructions in the original git-flow page and now I have this doubt.

Comment: @KeithThompson no, after I've deleted the `<branch>` branch locally.

Comment: Sorry, I confused "develop" and "<branch>". Your question might be clearer if you used an actual branch name. If you actually typed `git branch -d <branch>` the shell would complain because `<` and `>` are metacharacters.

Comment: Yep, I see now that using `<branch>` to name a general branch might be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; `<branch>` is only removed locally by virtue of `git branch -d <branch>`, but a copy of it exists on remote (if it was pushed there prior).  This can be verified by running `git branch -vvvv`, which will show the remote branch with no associated local tracking branch.

`git push origin develop` will *only* push `develop` to your remote repository (origin) without touching anything else (barring any commit hooks).  If `<branch>` did exist remotely and you wanted to delete it, you would have to add the deletion operation as a separate step (`git push origin :<branch>`).

Comment: Thank you Makoto. I'll have to remove the branch remotely with `git push origin --delete <branch>` then. A small doubt: what is the difference between `git push` and `git push origin develop` in this context? Will the second cmmd do something the first one does not?

Comment: @Gabriel:  Depends on your configuration settings.  `git push <remote> <branch>` is the absolutely unambiguous way to push a specific branch to a specific remote.  `git push` will do so if your configuration allows for you to do so based on context.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comment. Now that I understand what you're asking the answer is no. In the git-flow model the feature branch is not pushed to remote, so all actions affect your local git repository.

If you've pushed your feature branch to the remote repo, you'll need to delete it manually.